# How to use different values for Cognos Bar chart labels than underlying values

Tags: bar-chart, cognos

I am trying to create a bar chart in cognos where the bars are each representing percentages of actuals to forecast but I would like to have a label coming off of each bar that shows the actual value (as opposed to the percentage value). Anyone know if this is possible? Thanks in advance.

Environment is Cognos 10.2.1.

Comment: If your actual is more than forecast, should the bar 'peek' above the 100% line? You could use the 100% stacked chart but all bars are the same height. There's a way to trick it but first consider what happens when actual is larger than forecast - does the bar appear above all the others?

Comment: It is very common for our actuals to be greater than our forecasts. We ended up developing 2 charts, one where actuals were displayed in percentages of forecast and one where we did a clustered bar chart with the clusters consisting of two bars: actual and forecast dollar amounts. After many hours we figured it wasn't worthwhile to keep attempting to get the dollar figures as labels on the percentage graph.